# Django template variables not working

Tags: django, templates

(I am new to Django)

I'm having a problem with my Django template.

The cruise_details filter should only return one row, but when I try and display this in the template with cruise_details.port for example, nothing is displayed. "code" is correctly getting passed from the URL.

If I remove .port and just put cruise_details I am presented with this on the page

```
<QuerySet [<Cruise: B724>]>
```

view.py

```
def cruise(request, code):

return render(request, 'cruise.html', {
        'cruise_details': Cruise.objects.filter(code=code)
})
```

cruise.html

```
{{ cruise_details.port}}
```

models.py

```
class Cruise(models.Model):
code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
destination = models.CharField(max_length=60)
url = models.URLField
ship = models.ForeignKey(Ship)
duration = models.IntegerField
start = models.DateField
end = models.DateField
added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
port = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `Cruise.objects.filter(code=code)` returns a list, so if there are many possible matches you can modify your template to show them all

```
{% for cruise_detail in cruise_details %}
    {{ cruise_details.port }}
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively, if you know there can only be one result then you can use `get` instead:

```
 Cruise.objects.get(code=code)
```

and your existing template should work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using .get did it! Thanks a lot